# Segmentation Violation Error When Running Simple CUDA Kernel in Go

Tags: go, cuda

I'm trying to run a simple CUDA kernel using the Go programming language, but I'm encountering a segmentation violation error. The error occurs when I try to launch the kernel using the `cu.LaunchKernel` function.

Here's the code I'm using:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mumax/3/cuda/cu"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "unsafe"
)

func runHelloWorldKernel() {
    // Initialize CUDA
    cu.Init(0)
    device := cu.Device(0)
    ctx := cu.CtxCreate(cu.CTX_SCHED_AUTO, device)
    defer cu.CtxDestroy(&ctx)

    // Set the current context
    cu.CtxSetCurrent(ctx)

    // Load the compiled PTX kernel
    ptx, err := ioutil.ReadFile("helloWorld.ptx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read PTX file: %v", err)
    }
    mod := cu.ModuleLoadData(string(ptx))
    kernel := cu.ModuleGetFunction(mod, "helloKernel")

    // Allocate memory for the result
    resultDev := cu.MemAlloc(4) // int is 4 bytes
    defer cu.MemFree(resultDev)

    // Execute the kernel
    cu.LaunchKernel(
        kernel,
        1, 1, 1, // grid size
        1, 1, 1, // block size
        0, cu.Stream(0),
        []unsafe.Pointer{
            unsafe.Pointer(resultDev),
        },
    )

    // Copy the result back to the host
    var result int32
    cu.MemcpyDtoH(unsafe.Pointer(&result), resultDev, 4)

    // Print the result
    fmt.Printf("Result from kernel: %d\n", result)
}

func main() {
    runHelloWorldKernel()
}
```

This is the result

```
CUDA initialized
Using device: 0
Context created
Context set as current
unexpected fault address 0x7f728c800000
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x7f728c800000 pc=0x48fc6a]
```

I have also run cuda samples and the drivers are running correctly. I have also tried `github.com/barnex/cuda5/cu`.

I'm not sure what's causing this segmentation violation.

Comment: Without a stack trace it's basically impossible to say why.

Comment: 0x00000000004b9e9e in github.com/mumax/3/cuda/cu.LaunchKernel (f=10981456, gridDimX=1, gridDimY=1, gridDimZ=1, blockDimX=1, blockDimY=1, blockDimZ=1, 
sharedMemBytes=0, stream=0, kernelParams=...) at /home/patrykg/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mumax/3@v3.9.3+incompatible/cuda/cu/execution.go:24
24                      *((*uint64)(offset(argv, i))) = *((*uint64)(kernelParams[i])) // argv[i] = *kernelParams[i]

Comment: @talonmies thanks that was the output from the stacktrace. i ran it using gdb, is there another way?

Comment: Please put relevant information in the question not comments

Comment: The kernel arguments you are passing is causing the segfault. Why I cannot say because I don't know how that Go wrapper works, nor have I ever written code in Go

Comment: I agree, if the segfault is isolated to the line of code that launches the kernel: `cu.LaunchKernel(...` then the problem is almost certainly in the arguments you are passing to that call. Without the kernel code to refer to, I'm unable to determine whether you are making the right choices, even if I were a go programmer, which I am not.  But that is where I would start.  Study what you are doing in that call, and compare it to a known good call in an example code, somewhere.  Ideally a known good call for the same kind of kernel parameters (i.e. similar prototype).